# いつかこれがビジネスになればなあと

Tags: grammar

Would be grateful if someone could translate the following:

> いつかこれがビジネスになれば**なあ**と

I'm also not sure what the function of  "な" is in the end part
になればなあと.

My translation attempt: Someday this will become a business after.

Comment: Did you read the Leebo's comment in your previous question? [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799). This question is welcome if you focus only on the usage of なあ. Please post your translation attempt for the remaining part of the sentence.

Comment: Sorry Naruto. :(

Comment: My translation attempt :  Someday this will become a business after . Yes its the last part I am not sure about.  Sorry again :(

Answer (score 2):

This なあ (also written as なぁ, なー, な) is a sentence-final particle with several meanings, but here it is used to add deep emotion. It's like "oh" or an exclamation mark in English.

- おいしいなあ。 Oh it's delicious.
- 上手だなあ。 You're so skillful!
- よく食べるなあ。 Oh you're a big eater!

This type of なあ can follow a ば-form, too, like so:

- もっとお金があれば…。 If I had more money...
- もっとお金があればなあ。 Oh if only I had more money!

Likewise, いつかこれがビジネスになればなあ means "I wish this will become a business some day". The speaker is feeling the chance is not very high. と at the end is just a quotative particle that indicates this is what someone said or thought.

Comment: Thanks so much Naruto ! - I really appreciate it ! :)

Comment: Just want to say Thank you again Naruto for answering both my questions. I really really appreciate it alot.  Thanks once again .