# Does なればと思って have the implications of なればいいと思って?

Tags: sentence, conditionals

大きな仕事がしたいと言ったお前の大きなチャレンジになればと思ってお願いしたんです

What is the exact nuance of なればと思ってin this sentence?

I understand it's "You said you wanted a big job, so thinking it'd be a big challenge for you, I gave it to you"

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is fine. As mentioned in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78382/45489), なれば alone can be used to express wishing. It is similar to *If (only) ...* in English. I think the closest translation would be *wondering if...*

BTW using お前 in です sentence is odd. It should be あなた (or at least 君).